# How to split a C-String into an array of C-Strings

Tags: c++, strtok, argv, c-strings

In C++, I want to do

```
char buffer[1024] = "command insert file1 file2 ..."
```

and turn it into

```
*argv[0] = "command"
*argv[1] = "insert"
*argv[2] = "file1"
```

et cetera. Isn't there some simple way to do this, like split() or whatever? I can't use boost or vectors because the elements need to be c-strings for linux library functions (like execvp), and they need to compile on a server without boost or any extra libraries

I've seen examples online that use strtok, but the examples don't seem to store the values afterward, just print them. The other way seems to be some ridiculously complicated method that involves looping through and counting spaces and escape characters.
Isn't there an easier way? This is driving me nuts.

EDIT: As a point of reference, this is what my main function looks like so far:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void runCommand(char **argv);
void splitIntoArgs(char *command, char **argv);

int main()
{

   char buffer[1024];
   char *argv[5];

   while (1)
   {
       // prompt user for command to run
       cout << "Enter command: ";
       cin >> buffer; //read the buffer
       cout << endl;
       splitIntoArgs(buffer, argv); //split the command into separate arguments
       if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
           return 0;
       runCommand(argv);
   }

}
```

Comment: isn't arguments already just like how you want this, i don't think you need to work for it. See here for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: I'm making a rudimentary shell, that's why. It doesn't take these variables as arguments when the program starts. I'll edit my question to explain this

Comment: `strtok` should work fine.  Did you run into a problem storing the pointers?

Comment: BTW, assuming `char** argv`, then `*argv[0]` is a single character, not a string.  Did you mean `argv[0] = "command";` ?

Comment: You could just replace the spaces by zéros and store the pointers to the starts of the strings in buffer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: That's what `strtok` does.

Comment: @BenVoigt : right so strtok is the way to go after all.

Comment: Just because the examples you found of `strtok()` just show printing them, that doesn't mean it's the only thing you can do. You can store the values just as well.

Comment: But what is the code to have strtok store a token? @Ben Voigt isn't it an array of character pointers, not characters, so it should be *argv[0]?

Comment: @qwerty26: `argv` is an array of character pointers.  `*argv` and `argv[0]`, which are the same thing, are a single character pointer.  `*argv[0]` is a single character.  You might be looking for `argv[0] = strtok( blah, blah );`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a strtok() version of splitting the command:

```
char** split(char *command, int* size) {
  char** ret;
  char* t;
  int i;
  for(i=0, t=strtok(command, " "); t!=NULL;++i ) {
    ret[i]=t;
    t = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  *size = i;
  return ret;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
char** args;
int nArgs;
args = split(buffer, &nArgs);
// you can now eg. execvp("/bin/ls", args)
```

Comment: Is this correct? No initialization? Looks to me that you will be corrupting memory here and there...

Answer (score 1):

You asked this as a c++ question, so why don't you use the power of c++ in the form of the standard library which gives you `std::string` and `std::vector`

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str){
    std::vector res;
    size_t old_position = 0;
    for(size_t position = 0; position = str.find(" ", position); position != std::npos){
        res.push_back(res.substr(position, position-old_position));
        old_position = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can use c++ strings, and perhaps not vectors since I am using the elements of the array in a c function. Perahps someone knows the execvp, execlp etc functions better and can say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
// split string str on " ". The result array has count elements, 
// so make sure count > #of spaces + 1
char** split(char* str, int count){
   char** res = new char*[count];
   int res_i = 0;
   for(int i=0; str[i] != 0 && res_i < count; ++i){
       if(str[i] == ' '){
          res[res_i++] = i + 1;
          str[i] = 0;
       }
   }
   return res;
}
```

A couple of notes:

- this code is not safe use. If for example the last character of "str" is a ' ', you would get a pointer to the null-terminator '\0'.
- the standard reply to someone using `char*` for not specific reason in a c++ question still applies: use [`std::string`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)!
- `split` destroys the original string that was passed to it

Comment: this does not give you the desired result. see my other question